# How to generate a Swagger file for a REST API

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

My requirement is to generate a Swagger File for  a given ReST API URL. I have invoked the below mentioned URLs using POSTMAN client and it was working fine.

However, for this URL to use in Informatica, it's required to have associated Swagger file either json or yaml format.

I am just an end user to ReST API and not aware of its code.

Below are URLs which were used.

https://app.informaticaondemand.com/ma/api/v2/user/login [Method=POST]

https://app2.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/activity/activityLog?rowLimit=1000 [Method=GET]

Please suggest any 3rd party utilities to help to create Swagger Files out of providing these APIs.

Thanks,

Tom George

Comment: There is a "How to get started?" section [here](http://swagger.io/getting-started/) that could be helpful, in your case it is the second approach

Answer (score -2):

You could use [OpenAPI designer](https://openapi.design/). It's an easy to use, self explaining swagger generator. Fill out the required forms in the "Header" tab and then  add the login and activitylog paths in the tab "Paths"

Comment: This will 'generate', but the question claims that it is a client and knows nothing of the design, so how will the user design something he knows nothing about.